# 'FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT' in new flavors of Android OS(4.4 & later)

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack

Recently, I faced a problem to re-initiate Activity that's already in back-stack. The flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) is the best solution for manage this problem. But in Android 4.4 & later it isn't work well(some times Activity view is getting freezes or Application minimizes itself, menu isn't inflated to re-initiated Activity or Keyboard isn't allow to enter something to text area) but in previous versions this flag re-initiate's the Activity, and removed from back stack. Please review [this link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63570#c2) for more details.

Comment: Please explain what "isn't work well" means.

Comment: @ CommonsWare, FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT is useful to re-initiate activity when that's already in back-stack. but in 4.4 & later, some times Activity view is going to freezing state or Application minimizes itself. This is already reported to Google. Please refer 'https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63570#c2' for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Android 4.4 & later, the application misbehaves when **`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`** flag is used in Activity creation. The major issues are, some times Activity is going to freeze state, when navigate to another activity key board isn't working well(key board is shown but user can't enter anything to text area), didn't inflate menu, or Application navigates to minimize state.

I think this issue is related to back-stack and flow of activity, when launcher activity(in my application, SplashScreenActivity is a launcher) finishes, then sub-activity causes some problem when using **`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`** to re-initiate previous Activity. So in this scenario, don't kill launcher or parent activity & start next activity using `startActivityForResult(childAcivityIntent, requestcode)`, & kill parent activity at the time of `onActivityResult` call. And also remember don't use `singleInstance` or `singleTop` flags in child & parent activities.

```
private void onStartNextActivity() {
        Intent mIntent= new Intent(SplashscreenActivity.this, ChildActivity.class);
                 mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
       startActivityForResult(mIntent, 1111);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==1111)
            finish();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue:
When I am coming back to the parent `Activity` by setting the `Intent` flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` from child activity, some times Application is minimized in Nexus5 with Android Marshmallow.

I struggled for 3 days and at last I change the Launch mode of `activity` to `Single Task`.

Now My application is working fine.