# What could cause an Android app to be sent to the background?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, start-activity

I am working on an android app where there are two activities that switch back and forth using startActivity with the FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT flag.   One activity is a fairly standard Android activity that uses fragments.  The second activity is a wrapper for interactive animation screens created with Unity.  The problem that I see occasionally is that after one activity starts the other, the second one will display fine, however, as soon as you tap anywhere on the second activity, the app's screen will close as if you had tapped on the Android Home button.  No exceptions are logged, the app is still listed as an active app, and you can resume the application and continue from where you left off.   Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Comment: Please provide code

Comment: It's an extremely large project.    I've not yet been able to reproduce the problem in a standalone project.  Currently, I'm just trying to see if anyone else has ever seen this behavior before and get some hints on what might be causing the problem.

Comment: Have you tried adding this flags when starting the new activity and tapping the Home button  `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);`

Comment: This app needs to run as a "kiosk" app and will be calling Activity.startLockTask().   So I can't use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK as these would take me out of the lock task.

Comment: This thread mentions the same behavior. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316451/flag-activity-reorder-to-front-in-new-flavors-of-android-os4-4-later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this problem is caused by a bug in Android.   See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37070093

I created a video showing the problem - https://userbob.com/ReorderToFront.mp4

Here's the code that demonstrates the problem - https://userbob.com/ReorderToFrontTest.zip

For me it seemed like the problem only occurred if the activity I was trying to reorder to front was currently the root Activity of its task stack.   So I created a new activity to sit at the root of the task that calls startActivity for a second activity in the onCreate method.

```
public class RootActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent( this, MainActivity.class );
        startActivity( intent );
    }
}
```